# How to keep your data during ajax call in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In my asp.net page, I am using ajax, and I want to know how to keep the variable data when doing an ajax call. Basically on page load, I download a lot of information from a database and display it on the page. Then during an ajax call, I want to use the data stored in the variable, but the problem is, during the ajax call, that data goes away, and I have to re download the data again.

Is there a way to keep it during the ajax call?

Comment: Could you post your code and possibly elaborate more? I'm a little confused on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.net you have to many ways to do this, `Session["YourNameHere"]` you have the vale until the sesion is closed or `ViewState["YourNameHere"]` you have the value in the page until It is closed.

Some links [Using ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or
[Using SesionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
I hope this help.

**EDIT**

Using the Viewstate.

1. First put serializable in you class.

   ```
   [Serializable]
   public class Fruits 
   {
       public string Apple { get; set; }}
   ```
2. Save The value:

   `Fruits Fruit = YourMethod(); //Yor method that retrive the data from DataBase*
   ViewState["Fruit"] = Fruit;`
3. when you'll use the Viewstate:

   `Fruits Fruit = ViewState["Fruit"]`

Comment: I want to use viewstates, but I don't know how to save complex objects in it. I made another thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470510/how-to-searalize-complex-objects-and-put-them-in-a-viewstate-in-asp-net.

Answer (score 1):

```
I want to use the data stored in the variable, but the problem is, during the ajax call, that data goes away, and I have to re download the data again.
```

This isn't a problem, it's the nature of http and stateless environments.

Depending on the type of data retrieved you there are some mechanisms to cache the values:
application state, session, cache, cookie, static dictionary. It really depends on the context of the data, the usage scenario, the hardware etc.

Your best approach is to avoid caching the object until you know that this is the bottleneck in the system, or for this particular feature.

Comment: So really, in any ajax or postback request, you will lose the session and all its data and will start with a new one?

Comment: in one word: yes. that's the nature of a stateless environment such as http.