# How to serialize complex objects and put them in a ViewState?

Tags: asp.net, xml, serialization, sharepoint-2010, xml-serialization

I have an object of type `List<SPSection>`, the `SPSection` is a custom class that contains a `string` and a `List<SPListItem>`, `SPListItem` is a SharePoint object representing an item.

I want to store this in a `ViewState`, but I don't know how to do this. Is there a way to serialize this or convert it to some binary string, so that I could put it in a `ViewState`. Also when getting the value back from the `ViewState`, how can I convert it back to `List<SPSection>`.

Thanks

Comment: How have you tried to serialize it so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this.** `SPListItem` instances **cannot be retained between requests**. They depend on the respective `SPList` instance, which in turn depends on `SPWeb` + `SPSite`, both instantiated automatically and provided through `SPContext`.

What you can do is retain item `ID`s between requests. Your custom classes need to be binary serializable, i.e. marked with the `[Serializable]` interface. You then just store your object under a given key into the view state: `ViewState["MyObjects"] = myObjects;`.

Comment: I see you can use `GetDataTable` on the `SPList` and perhaps filter for the specific item. Also, for Event Receivers I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg981880(v=office.14).aspx#UsingEventReceiversInSPFPart2_LoggingEvents) shows using GetEnumerator on the property bag to build a set of `DictionaryEntry` items.